# Combine rows in Dataframe column based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have the excerpt of the following `df`:

```
                     Causa de muerte   Sexo              Edad  Periodo   Total
39  001-102  I-XXII.Todas las causas  Total    Menos de 1 año     2018    1027
40  001-102  I-XXII.Todas las causas  Total    Menos de 1 año     2017    1092
41  001-102  I-XXII.Todas las causas  Total    Menos de 1 año     2016    1120
78  001-102  I-XXII.Todas las causas  Total     De 1 a 4 años     2018     240
79  001-102  I-XXII.Todas las causas  Total     De 1 a 4 años     2017     226
80  001-102  I-XXII.Todas las causas  Total     De 1 a 4 años     2016     248
```

Is there a way to combine/merge the rows where 'Edad' == 'Menos de 1 año' and 'Edad' == 'De 1 a 4 años' and rename the merged rows to 'De 0 a 4 años'.
My goal is that the corresponding numbers in 'Total' add up:

```
                     Causa de muerte   Sexo              Edad  Periodo   Total
39  001-102  I-XXII.Todas las causas  Total     De 0 a 4 años     2018    1267
40  001-102  I-XXII.Todas las causas  Total     De 0 a 4 años     2017    1318
41  001-102  I-XXII.Todas las causas  Total     De 0 a 4 años     2016    1368
```

I'm assuming you'll do it with groupby, but I haven't figured out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) with aggregate `sum`:

```
df['Edad'] = df['Edad'].replace({'Menos de 1 año':'De 1 a 4 años'})

df = df.groupby(['Causa de muerte','Sexo','Edad','Periodo'], as_index=False)['Total'].sum()
print (df)
                    Causa de muerte   Sexo           Edad  Periodo  Total
0  001-102  I-XXII.Todas las causas  Total  De 1 a 4 años     2016   1368
1  001-102  I-XXII.Todas las causas  Total  De 1 a 4 años     2017   1318
2  001-102  I-XXII.Todas las causas  Total  De 1 a 4 años     2018   1267
```

Comment: Same idea, faster than me :)

Comment: Just tried it, but it doesn't seem to work. 
The numbers in 'Total' don't seem to add up and in 'Edad' it stays 'De 1 a 4 años', whereas it should be 'De 0 a 4 años'.

It basically should add the number in 'Total' for the two age groups 'Menos de 1 año' (less than one year) and 'De 1 a 4 años' (from 1 to 4 years) and call it 'De 0 a 4 años' (from 0 to 4 years)

Comment: @LeLuc - So replacement not working? Is possible some whitespaces?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. 
I also tried 
`df_m['Edad'] = df_m['Edad'].replace({'Menos de 1 año':'De 0 a 4 años'})`

But that just keeps the two groups and doesn't merge them.

Comment: @LeLuc - What is `print (df['Edad'].unique())` before my solution?

Comment: `['Todas las edades' 'Menos de 1 año' 'De 1 a 4 años' 'De 5 a 9 años'
 'De 10 a 14 años  ' 'De 15 a 19 años  ' 'De 20 a 24 años'
 'De 25 a 29 años' 'De 30 a 34 años' 'De 35 a 39 años' 'De 40 a 44 años'
 'De 45 a 49 años' 'De 50 a 54 años' 'De 55 a 59 años' 'De 60 a 64 años'
 'De 65 a 69 años' 'De 70 a 74 años  ' 'De 75 a 79 años  '
 'De 80 a 84 años  ' 'De 85 a 89 años  ' 'De 90 a 94 años  '
 '95 y más años']`

so basically combine the second and third element to add the numbers in 'Total' and call the row in 'Edad' 'De 0 a 4 años'.

Comment: @LeLuc - It seems there is whitespace, try `df_m['Edad'] = df_m['Edad'].str.strip()` before my solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227541/discussion-between-leluc-and-jezrael).